# How to remove defaultnamespace from w3c dom Node?

Tags: java, xml

From the input xml, using XPathAPI.selectsingleNode() a node is fetched. The node has the xml defaultnamespace.

Need to remove the defaultnamespace

...

node.removeAttributeNS() is not working.
Please suggest

Comment: Why do you want to remove the default namespace?

Comment: Please show some code and a sample of the XML you're starting from and the XML you want to get in the end.  I suspect there's more to the problem than what you've said so far, since removing the namespace declaration "attribute" from the parsed XML tree won't affect the namespace of that node or any of its descendants - the namespace is part of a node's name, and you can't change the name of an existing DOM node, you can only create a new node with the different name.

Comment: Trying to get a node from one xml and getting it appended to another xml. The node fetched from the old xml is having the default namespace which is not required in the new xml.